# Locating Office365 unc and mounting it via powershell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, office365

Scenario:
I have a newly created Office365 realm for an arbitrary domain. I need to mount the Sharepoint/OneDrive piece of it as a drive via powershell. This seems to be possible as can be seen here:
[Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/4487acf6-cf76-4cd2-9fd2-5dbd8f0ccdee/newpsdrive-to-sharepoint-office-365?forum=ITCG)

My problem is, how do I determine exactly what the unc is that I need to pass into New-PSDrive?

My tests have been failing miserably:

```
New-PSDrive -Name T -PSProvider FileSystem -Root '\\test.onmicrosoft.com@SSL\Documents' -Credential $Creds
New-PSDrive : The network path was not found
```

Edit: Just to make things more clear: Given an office365 account with a particular username, what is the path to the root directory of sharepoint and/or onedrive for that account? I'll try and figure the powershell out

Answer (score 0):

After some serious trial and error, I discovered the correct URL. Leaving it here for others:

Given a company named 'test' and a user defined as "user", your unc and creds would be:

Credentials would need to be:

```
username: user@test.onmicrosoft.com

New-PSDrive -Name J -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\test-my.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\personal\user_test_onmicrosoft_com\Documents
```